# Sufficient conditions for being a harmonic function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real-valued function defined on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb R^2$. Suppose that $f$ is twice differentiable separately in each variable and satisfies Laplace's equation $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0$. Using the given information, we cannot conclude that $f$ is even continuous, let alone twice continuously differentiable. Therefore, we cannot guarantee that $f$ is harmonic.

My questions are:

1. Suppose we know that $f$ is continuous. Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?
2. Suppose we know that $f$ is differentiable. Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?
3. Suppose we know that $f$ is continuously differentiable. Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?
4. Suppose we know that $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yx}$ exist. Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?
5. Suppose we know that $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$ are continuous. Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?
6. Suppose we know that $f$ is twice differentiable (but not continuously so!). Is this sufficient to guarantee that $f$ is harmonic?

Comment: Could you share your counterexamples? It might help other people get an idea/tweak to fit the other cases.

Comment: @Jose27: I just realized I got confused. I thought I had a counterexample, but that is not the case. Apologies.